# drupal profile date format

Tags: drupal, date, format

I added some users from an excel via a script to my drupal database. This works fine except for one thing, i use the profile module to store some information, one of them is the date of birth.

In my excel the date is stored like '18/02/1995' but in the database a date field has a format like this 'a:3:{s:5:"month";s:1:"2";s:3:"day";s:2:"18";s:4:"year";s:4:"1995";}'
Of course the date's all come out the wrong  way in drupal. So i have to convert my date's to drupal date's.

So i would like to know what kind of format this is and is there a function to convert my date's to this format?

(if it is in any way possible to do this in sql or excel that would even be more excellent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [serialize](http://php.net/serialize):

```
serialize(array('month' => '2', 'day' => '18', 'year' => '1995'));
```

It will output:

```
a:3:{s:5:"month";s:1:"2";s:3:"day";s:2:"18";s:4:"year";s:4:"1995";}
```